# Unit testing ConsoleAppender log4j

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I'm trying to internally change the layout of a custom exception.  To unit test this I'm looking to capture the console output.  I've captured console output before but the method I used for that previously doesn't seem to have the expected result with log4j.

If I wanted to capture console output, I'd use:

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(baos);
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    final String consoleOutput = baos.toString();
```

The value of consoleOutput would then be "Hello World!".

If I apply this to log4j using:

```
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(baos);
    System.setOut(printStream);
    LOGGER.debug("Simple message");
    final String consoleOutput = baos.toString();
```

consoleOutput is empty.  Looking at the javadoc for ConsoleAppender I see:

> The default target is System.out.

If I change my code to just include the line:

```
   LOGGER.debug("Simple message");
```

I see the expected result in the console:

> 2013-06-02 19:49:46,818 DEBUG  [com.parlance.LoggingTest] - Simple
>   message

So I was assuming that this would work but have obviously missed something and have been left scratching my head!

**UPDATE**

I just tried something and if I change the creation of my logger class to be AFTER I call System.setOut, it appears to work:

```
  final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(baos);
  System.setOut(printStream);
  final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingTest.class);
  logger.debug("Simple message");
  final String consoleOutput = baos.toString();
```

This has the desired effect but isn't great if I want to Logger to be static.  Any ideas why this happens and how to address the original question without declaring the logger this way?

Comment: Damn I was looking for something similar, but I guess it's silly of me to expect 9 year old code to still work :))

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `System.setOut` is being called after the initialisation of log4j. log4j initialises using the value of `System.out` (it will keep a reference to it). You can get around  it by calling `System.setOut` before log4j as you've said.

For static loggers it gets harder; you can use the option

```
-Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true
```

This means that log4j doesn't get initialised automatically, but you'll still need to arrange that the `System.setOut` gets called before the first logger.

For more information, see [Short introduction to log4j (section Default Initialization Procedure)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)